# ffmpeg - works through terminal, but not online

Tags: ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg onto the server using the terminal. All I need it for is to generate a thumbnail when someone uploads a video. I tested the command in Terminal, and it works great. However, when I post it to the site, nothing happens. No errors and no thumbnails are generated.

Does anybody know why this is? I read something about the server is running as a different user than what I log in with. I don't really understand that though, and there was no information on how to gain the proper permissions or switch to a user that has the permissions already. All I found was how to show the current user and list all users through SSH.

When I try and do anything in Terminal using `usermod`, I get the following error:

```
-bash: usermod: command not found
```

So can I modify permissions for a user, or change the user that it's using somehow?

Comment: What server?  What server-side language?  Yes you are right, that this is likely a permissions problem.

Comment: It's on a Linux server and I'm using php. I got a response from the hosting company saying that I have to install ffmpeg-php as well. Since it works through the Terminal, I doubt it, but is that true for front end usage?

Comment: There is a PHP extension, `ffmpeg-php`, but you don't need to do that if you want to run FFmpeg with `exec()` or similar.  Are you specifying the full path to the `ffmpeg` binary?

Comment: Yes, I'm even checking to see if it exists and it returns true.